# Old Mac Quadra HD - how to connect to USB?

Tags: sata-to-usb

Archiving some hard drives from some old Macs.

The oldest mac, a mid 90's Macintosh Quadra 650 has a SATA drive which does not work with my SATA->USB converter.

It has this connector...

[image]

Can anyone suggest what type of converter I would need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a SCSI-1 drive which requires a SCSI to USB adapter.

These exist but are usually intended to connect a SCSI enclosure to a USB port. SCSI enclosures typically have different kind of SCSI-2 50-PIN (or even a 68-PIN) connectors on the outside so you are going to need a second conversion step.

Easiest is to get the enclosure itself too. And you have to make sure its internal wiring is suited for the 50-pin ribbon cable used by SCSI-1 and older SCSI-2, which matches the connector on your drive.
A SCSI-2 enclosure will work fine with a SCSI-1 drive. It's backwards compatible.

The alternative solution is to buy a SCSI-2 PCI controller-card for a PC to which you can attach the drive directly. This will be a LOT cheaper. 2nd hand cards can be had for as little as $20.
If you go this route look for the following brands: Adaptec, LSI, Symbios.
Those have best driver support in Windows, but for Windows 10 (and 64-bit) finding drivers for very old cards might be a big problem. Just about ANY SCSI controller from these brands will work with Linux.